# QGIS point displacement of only unique point classes/symbols

Tags: qgis

I am mapping various archaeological sites as points; as this is a very rough map, some of the sites share the same coordinates. The points are categorized by the type of site (as "category 1", e.g. settlement, fortifications sanctuary, necropolis etc.). Sometimes, at a single location there are multiple points/datasets per category, like multiple types of fortifications ("category 2").
I chose Point Displacement to declutter the symbols, as seen below. In a next step I just want to show only one symbol per category 1.

In the example below there are three types of fortifications (the tower symbol), like actual towers, walls, fortresses etc. But I just want it to display a single tower-symbol to show that there are fortifications in general (not showing all of them).

Is there any way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach from the Field calculator is:

[image]

(1) Create a new column to single out the representative with an expression:

```
@row_number = minimum(@row_number, 
                      group_by:=concat(geom_to_wkt($geometry) + to_string("type")))
```

[image]

In this expression I used only one category `"type"`. Please add your secondary category (*e.g*. `+to_string("type") +to_string("type2")...`) as necessary.

(2) Filter the data

[image]

Comment: I thought about something similar (as this is much more down to my skill level^^), but this approach would be a one-time fixed thing, right? I was hoping to keep it all modular in a way that I could make changes to the underlying datasheet (its a CSV from Excel) without having to do any new calculations in GIS itself everytime.

Comment: @StefanBiernath Yes, you are right. Unless `Create virtual field` is chosen, the output field is pretty much fixed.

Comment: So a virtual field does adapt to changes to the file? Cool!
I tried using your suggested expression "@row_number = minimum(@row_number, group_by:=concat(geom_to_wkt($geometry) + to_string("cat1")))" but didn't get any results...

Comment: @Kazuhito : would u be kind enough to indicate some references about the use of `$geometry` in the group_by section ? i saw u made some answers of this kind on **gis.stack.exchange** but information are very scarce and i didn't anything clear in QGIS help ... even the right syntax to use seems mysterious to me ...

Comment: Hi @snaileater I am probably not the qualified person... I think the useful situation of `group_by` is to single out some particular record (or row) to narrow down multiple records. It's the same idea you have presented as to `Distinct`. It's merit is that we can stick with the Field calculator (without learning Virtual layer, Spatialite, or Postgres... ).

Comment: I was able to make this method work with this expression: `if("id" = minimum("id", concat(geom_to_wkt($geometry), "cat1")), "id", 0)`

Comment: Thanks @csk But I am wondering what the syntax returns by `minimum()` part.

Comment: I think minimum("field", groupby expression, optional filter expression) returns the smallest value of the field for features within the group, optionally filtered by filter expression). So in this case it returns the minimum value of the id field for points with the same geometry, filtered by the cat1 value.

Comment: Your original syntax was mostly good, it just needed a conditional expression.

Comment: @csk Sorry but I am honestly not be able to understand your syntax, and your observation that my syntax lacks conditional nature. Have you tested them?

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of your data ? You'are able to create a query that first filter your data and let only **one type of object per site**.

Something like the following :

```
Select distinct type_of_point, site_geom group by site_geom
```

And then u map the result of that query.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my data structure.

I am not very well versed in SQL, but I tried to adapt your suggestion into the query of a virtual layer. I got the error "no such column: cat1". I don't know why it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Can u post your query ?